# Android leaderboard with two variables

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Hey fellow developers,

I have programmed a game in Android Studio and I want to set up a leaderboard for it. As it is convenient, I'd like to use the Google Leaderboard.

However, the rank of a player depends on two variables. In order to complete the game, the player needs to make certain moves. The less moves he needs, the better he ranks. This would cause having too many player with the same amount of moves. So there is another variable: the time the player needs to make these moves (it's a puzzle game so he needs to think about the moves).

The leaderboard should rank players according to their amount of moves. When 2 players have the same amount of moves, it depends on the time who is ranked higher. Is that possible with the Google Play Leaderboard? If yes, how can I implement this? If not, do you have any other suggestion/recommendation?

I also thought about calculating a score that depends on the moves and the time and then use that score for the leaderboard but this would only my 2nd choice.

I appreciate any useful comments and answers.

Cheers!

Comment: Why don't you do both? The number of moves and the amount of time it takes, with the time being your secondary value for calculating rank since it ties in with the efficiency of a player.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Pztar, but what exactly do you mean?
That's what I want to realize: one leaderboard that uses both values to calculate the rank. The question is how can I do it with the Google Play leaderboard?
Or do you mean, implement two different leaderboards (one with moves, one with time)?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Google Leaderboards, but the concept is simple enough. Why don't you just create an aggregate *score* variable? Then you can sort the leaderboard by the score, instead of two separate variables.

You can do this with an inverse function, something similar to this [answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/43965/73325) should work.

Also, from what I read quickly on the [Google Leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards) documentation, you should be able to have a leaderboard for each metric. One for the elapsed time and one for the moves taken (both sorted least to greatest). Then one more for the score, sorted greatest to least.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bryan, it is actually what I have implemented at the moment, it's just a few more lines of code so I did it as an interim solution but I would prefer having one leaderboard that has 2 variables. It's not the point here but imo it's more transparent and convenient for the user.

Comment: @Omega I see what you are saying. I took a quick look at the documentation, it seems like you should be able to load the data from every leaderboard created. It may be tricky, but you should be able to load the data from a "time", "moves" and "scores" leaderboard, then sort the data by the score value and only display the "time" and "moves" data (or all three). Again, I only took a quick look, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.